# List return type method returns only a single Item (last from List) C#.net

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I am trying to get ordered records from a list as follows:

```
 static Dictionary<string, List<Recomdendations>> productRecomdendationss = new Dictionary<string, List<Recomdendations>>();

  public List<Recomdendations> TopMatches(int id)
    {

        var name = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id==id).BkName;
        List<Recomdendations> books = LoadBooks().ToList();
        productRecomdendationss.Add(name,books);
        // grab of list of products that *excludes* the item we're searching for
        var sortedList = productRecomdendationss.Where(x => x.Key != name);

        sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);

        List<Recomdendations> Recomdendationss = new List<Recomdendations>();

        // go through the list and calculate the Pearson score for each product
        foreach (var entry in sortedList)
         {               
                 Recomdendationss.Add(new Recomdendations() { bookName =entry.Key , Rate = CalculatePearsonCorrelation(name, entry.Key) });

         }

        return Recomdendationss.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Rate).ToList();
    }
```

The problem arises when I try to add records to the list in the following lines:

```
   foreach (var entry in sortedList)
         {               
                 Recomdendationss.Add(new Recomdendations() { bookName =entry.Key , Rate = CalculatePearsonCorrelation(name, entry.Key) });

         }
```

It adds only the last of the records to list  While I require all the records to be added to list as ordered records. So how should I modify the code to return all the recommendations from the list. I have debugged the code and found this line of code to be problematic.

Comment: `sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)` doesn't change `sortedList` - it just returns an ordered sequence, which you're then ignoring. I suspect you want `var sortedList = productRecomdendationss.Where(x => x.Key != name).OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);`

Comment: The code works as expected. Which means that you don't understand some of the basic concepts, but you need to understand them to be able to ask the proper question - or at the very least know what you don't know so that you can point your question in that direction. I marked this for closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all `productRecomdendationss` is a dictinoary that holds tuple values `(string,  List<Recomdendations>)`.  By `productRecomdendationss.Add(name,books);` you add one tuple value to the dictionary which is okay.

> ```
>   var sortedList = productRecomdendationss.Where(x => x.Key != name);
>   sortedList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key);
> ```

With the code above, you tryna get a list of something while `productRecomdendationss` is not a list, it is a single item variable dictinoary. Lets assume where clause is okay and it returned you `books` list.

After this, you miss the point again that `sortedList` is a dictionary and I suppose you still assume it is a list and foreach onto that variable. And, this is also why you get your single item added to the returned list.

```
         // sortedList already holds a dictionary and its count 1
         foreach (var entry in sortedList)
         {               
                 Recomdendationss.Add(new Recomdendations() { bookName =entry.Key , Rate = CalculatePearsonCorrelation(name, entry.Key) });

         }
```

To achieve what you described, you should access to the list with `bool productRecomdendationss.TryGetValue("key", out sortedList))` and after that it would be alright to loop over its elements. Hope this approach solves your problem.

**Edit:**

To properly use TryGetValue() you can use if/else like shown below.

```
        // Correct key will return true and 
        //you can loop over the returned List<Recomdendations>
        if (productRecomdendationss.TryGetValue("key", out listOfRec))
        {
            //if true, listofRec will hold data from the dictionary.
            foreach (var entry in listOfRec)
            {               
                 //do your thing                 
            }
        }else
        {
          //Data with inquired key is not found
        }
```

Also, you can get the value from your dictionaty like this.

```
    // Check whether Dictionary contains data with this key.
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey("key"))
    {
        var value = dictionary["key"];  
    }
```

Comment: It's not working TryGetValue returns a bool value and sortedlist is also a dictionary variable

Comment: Yes, TryGetValue returns boolean and that value indicates that whether value is found with the key or not. But, it is not possible that sortedList is a dictionary if the key is correct and TryGetValue is returned true.

Comment: Now code runs fine but it returns 0 results when I pass first argument on run time and then 1 and 2 and 3 and so on. Also If I pass same argument (id ) twice , it says the key has already been passed. I want it to return all results when I pass id at first time.

Comment: So this is about getting results from dB correctly I suppose. If that helped you to understand what the problem is please accept my answer, so others can see how to handle similar problem.

Comment: it is about getting results from db and then order them on the basis of score (Rating)  , the recommendations class is responsible for handling temporary results . what I just want is the code should return a list of recommendations as I do in recommendations.add method. but instead of list it returns a singleton value. I accept this answer but I am not getting desired behavior.

Comment: Yes I get it but as you described it seems that problem is about getting correct list of data from the db. Also this is why you can not get those values from the dictionary variable. I believe once you get the values from db properly, you will be good to go. Have a nice day!